# How to see request causing 400 in Poem Web

Tags: logging, rust, rust-poem

I am using [poem-web](https://github.com/poem-web/poem) for building a web service but I am getting a 400 bad request to an endpoint but the log only shows

```
2023-05-16T05:45:45.190235Z DEBUG hyper::proto::h1::io: parsed 12 headers
2023-05-16T05:45:45.190280Z DEBUG hyper::proto::h1::conn: incoming body is content-length (1592 bytes)
2023-05-16T05:45:45.190346Z DEBUG hyper::proto::h1::conn: incoming body completed
2023-05-16T05:45:45.191518Z DEBUG hyper::proto::h1::io: flushed 220 bytes
```

Tracing is initiated as follows

```
    if env::var_os("RUST_LOG").is_none() {
        env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "poem=debug");
    }
    tracing_subscriber::fmt::init();
```

Does anyone know how I can get to see the body of the request that leads to the 400 response?

Comment: try `RUST_LOG=trace`

Answer (score 1):

Connect the `Tracing` middleware, which calls [`tracing`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/) crate methods inside.

```rust
use poem::middleware::Tracing;
let app = Route::new().at("/", index).with(Tracing);
```

Run `RUST_LOG=TRACE ./target/debug/app-name`. But I believe you haven't registered the route properly.